# obj[i] is not iterable in javascript while transforming data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to transform my data from one format to another format , but I am getting error `obj[i] is not iterable` why I want to get `expected output` as shown below in variable

```
const data = {
    "GENERAL": {
        "value": null,
        "type": "LABEL",
    },
    "Mobile NUMBER": {
        "value": "04061511",
        "type": "FIELD",

    },

   "Abc NUMBER": {
        "value": "89999",
        "type": "FIELD",

    },
    "Personal Info": {
        "value": null,
        "type": "LABEL",
    },
    "Address": {
        "value": "g-78",
        "type": "FIELD",

    }, "local": {
        "value": "090099",
        "type": "FIELD",

    }
}

const obj = {}
for (var i in data) {
    const {type} = data[i];
    if (type === 'LABEL') {
        obj[i] = []

    } else {
        obj[i] = [...obj[i], data[i]]
    }

}

console.log(obj)


const expectedout = {
    "GENERAL": [{
        "value": "04061511",
        "type": "FIELD",
        "displaytext": "Mobile NUMBER"

    }, {
        "value": "89999",
        "type": "FIELD",
        "displaytext": "Abc NUMBER"

    }],
  "Personal Info": [{
        "value": "g-78",
        "type": "FIELD",
        "displaytext": "Address"

    }, {
        "value": "090099",
        "type": "FIELD",
        "displaytext": "local"

    }]
}
```

Is there any better approach to transform my current data to expected data?I am ES6 in react
here is my code

https://jsbin.com/sesipuzeni/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Update

```
var obj = {
  "first":"first",
  "2":"2",
  "34":"34",
  "1":"1",
  "second":"second"
};
for (var i in obj) { console.log(i); };
VM5628:8
```

it seems object property don't have guarantee.yes is correct when you have number and string

but when you have always "string" it comes in same order

```
var obj = {
  "first":{a:"jjj"},
  "yyy":{a:"jjqej"},
  "ttt":{a:"jjsqj"},
  "ggg":{a:"jjjs"},
  "second":{a:"jjcj"}
};
for (var i in obj) { console.log(i); };
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You seem to be trying to combine adjacent properties into a single property containing an array of objects. But order of properties is not guaranteed in JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct order is not guaranteed

Comment: wait I will explain more

Comment: see my update my question

Comment: @Barmar yes I am trying to combine adjacent properties into a single property containing an array of objects

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. You are using obj[I] prior to it being assigned:     } else {
        obj[i] = [...obj[i], data[i]]
    }

Comment: When you iterate this way you always need to check if the object has this property. The function to do this is: hasOwnProperty - i.e `if( obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {..}..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you're processing the next element of the original object, `i` is no longer the key of the element containing the array of values. You need to save that in another variable.

```js
const data = {
  "GENERAL": {
    "value": null,
    "type": "LABEL",
  },
  "Mobile NUMBER": {
    "value": "04061511",
    "type": "FIELD",
  },

  "Abc NUMBER": {
    "value": "89999",
    "type": "FIELD",
  },
  "Personal Info": {
    "value": null,
    "type": "LABEL",
  },
  "Address": {
    "value": "g-78",
    "type": "FIELD",

  },
  "local": {
    "value": "090099",
    "type": "FIELD",
  }
}

const obj = {};
var lastLabel;
for (var i in data) {
  if (data[i].type === 'LABEL') {
    obj[i] = []
    lastLabel = i;
  } else {
    data[i].displaytext = i;
    obj[lastLabel] = [...obj[lastLabel], data[i]]
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Note that this whole approach depends on object properties retaining their order, which isn't guaranteed in JavaScript. But it happens to work in most existing implementations, I think.